# Changeing collection view cell height after swipping

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I implemented a way to swipe collection view cell. During this time, I want to unhidden a view, means when the swiping is done, the height of the cell should be a bit larger

```
    @objc func respondToSwipeRight(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: { [weak self] in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            this.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen
            this.container.setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: .init(x: 1, y: 1))
            this.container.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 15.degreesToRadians)
            haptic.impactOccurred()
            
            this.likeView.isHidden = false
            
        }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            
            this.rotateContainerToInitialPosition()
        })
    }

    private func rotateContainerToInitialPosition() {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6) { [weak self] in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            this.container.transform = .identity
            this.container.setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: .init(x: 0.5, y: 0.5))
            this.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.background
        }
    }
```

By the way, I set the height of cell dynamic

```
    collectionLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

In the above implementation, the `likeView`is appeared nicely with animation. But it shrinks the `imageView` above the `likeView`. They are in a `stackView`.
So I try to send a event handler that I can refresh the collectionView

```
   @objc func respondToSwipeRight(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: { [weak self] in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            this.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen
            this.container.setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: .init(x: 1, y: 1))
            this.container.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 15.degreesToRadians)
            haptic.impactOccurred()
            
            this.likeView.isHidden = false
            
        }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            
            this.rotateContainerToInitialPosition()
            this.eventHandler?(.reload) <---- event handler
        })
    }
```

```
  cell.view.eventHandler = { events in
        switch events {
        case .reload:
            collectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

It works well, but not so smooth and also won't be work in the first try but works after it. could anyone suggest a better way?

The other issue is, the `likeView` will be unhidden to another cell as well, which is I don't want. I want to do it only in that cell!

Thanks

Comment: Any help on it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to not use transform, but instead to declare a variable e.g desiredHeight for cells height and user UIScrollViewDelegates Method UIScrollViewDidScroll to track which cell you are using right now

this is just the example but you can easily modify it

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    let xOffSet = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    
    if xOffSet >= self.view.frame.width {
        self.desiredHeight = 100
    } else if xOffSet <= 0 {
        self.desiredHeight = 120
    }
    
}



}
```

Comment: It is not the full answer. You will have to modify it to make it work the way you want, but it is the correct way that I would use.